# How to save toggle switch in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, toggle

I am trying to create a Chrome extension which shows notifications after every hour. To receive notifications you must toggle a switch from the popup menu, however, right now once I toggle the switch and close the popup and then open the popup back up it shows the switch as off. Once the user turns the switch on it should remain on until the user turns it off again. I am using Javascript by the way. Any help on this?

[image]

```
if (checkbox.checked) {
    // this means the app is on and should display a notification every hour
} else {
    //this means the app is off and should NOT display a notification every hour
}
```

**Update**

I've tried all suggestions yet the everytime I reopen the popup the switch changes back to off. I think it might be something with my html? I have included it below:

```
   input:checked+.slider:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100px);
        transform: translateX(90px);
    }

    .slider:after {
        content: 'Turn on notifications';
        color: white;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'Candara';

    }

    input:checked+.slider:after {
        content: 'Turn off notifications';
    }
```

+++++++++++++++++++

```
        <div>
            <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
                <div class="slider round"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');



    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {

        if (checkbox.checked) {
          
            checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
                chrome.storage.local.set({ 'enabled': checkbox.checked }, 
                 function () {
                    console.log("confirmed");
                });
            })
```

Comment: FWIW, there are lots of examples around. Can't help without seeing a **proper** [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: Just added more info regarding the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to save user data like the state of the switch.

Example:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}, function() {
    console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
    console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

**Update #1:** based on your example:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
    chrome.storage.local.get('enabled', function (result) {
        if (result.enabled != null) {
            checkbox.checked = result.enabled;
        }
    });
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log(checkbox.checked);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ 'enabled': checkbox.checked }, function () {
            console.log("confirmed");
        });
    });
});
```

**Update #2:**

This is how your background.js could look like using the alarm and storage api to trigger a notification:

```
chrome.alarms.get('myAlarm', function (alarm) {
    if (alarm == null) {
        chrome.alarms.create('myAlarm', { periodInMinutes: 1 });
    }
});
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {
    chrome.storage.local.get('enabled', function(result) {
        if (result.enabled) {
            console.log('Show notification');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I have so far, but when I close the popup and open it back up it seems like the state did not save.  if (checkbox.checked) {
            chrome.storage.local.set({ 'input[type="checkbox"]': checkbox.checked }, function () {
                // Notify that we saved.
                console.log('Settings saved');
            });

Comment: I'm not sure how to read it. How would I write it with the code above?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if reading storage would keep the switch toggled when one closes the popup and opens it back up again

Comment: read the value from the storage as soon as the popup opens and set the switch value to the saved value. write the value to the storage as soon as the user clicks the switch. then you could use the [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) api for scheduling code to run periodically.

Comment: Still getting issues, I have updated my issue above

Comment: Why did you register two click event handler inside of each other? I will update my answer with an updated example.

Comment: Hmmm... you're right that second click event handler isn't necessary

Comment: Sorry one more question, how would I take care of this with a background script? In other words, every time I close popup.js the notifications no longer appear... I wanted it such that even though you close the popup AND the toggle is enabled then notifications will continue to display

Comment: The notification logic should be in the background script. Just check the value in the storage before sending the notification.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how I would check the storage in background.js? So I would check for the storage and simply add the logic for notifications? Nothing else? Like I don't have to add an eventListener?

Comment: I don't know how your notification logic looks like. Are you using the chrome alarms api or do you use the setInterval function to run the code for example every hour? Or something else? Lets say you are using the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function. Every time the provided callback function gets called, you can read the storage, like in the example from yesterday and show the notification based on the storage value.

Comment: I'm using the Chrome alarms api. So currently what you gave me yesterday I have it in the popup.js file. So in my background.js I would do something like:  chrome.storage.local.get('enabled',  function(result) {
    //notification logic here                                                                                                
   });

Comment: Exactly. I updated my answer with an additional example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using storage API is the easy way to save the option value persistently.
2. You need to trigger the `save` functionality when user interact with that checkbox. Mostly it's be binding click event handler to save.

```
checkbox.addEventListner('click', e=>{
   chrome.storage.local.set({key: value}..........}
})
```

Comment: So I tried that (updated code above) but the switch always goes back to it's original position

Comment: using Chrome developer panel, you can check the *saved* key/value in localStorage.